# Package installation command for redhat ubi-openjdk

Tags: java, docker, redhat

we were using the below image and command in our code to create image for our spring micro services and everything was working good.

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine

ARG IMAGE_EXPIRATION

LABEL quay.expires-after=$IMAGE_EXPIRATION`

RUN apk update && apk add bash curl dos2unix perl

RUN apk add krb5-dev krb5 krb5-pkinit 

RUN apk add lsof
```

Due to docker limit pull, we are getting into an issue to alpine image. when i asked my company to pull the above image and put in our quay repo. They informed me to use redhat openjdk.

I changed the code to below and now getting different errors.

```
FROM somehostname.com/redhat/ubi8-openjdk1.8

ARG IMAGE_EXPIRATION

LABEL quay.expires-after=$IMAGE_EXPIRATION

RUN yum update && yum install bash curl dos2unix perl

RUN yum install krb5-dev krb5 krb5-pkinit

RUN yum install lsof
```

I used yum but it says "yum not found" and when i used apt-get, received not found.

please let me know what is the command i need to use to install those packages.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You were already using `apk`, why did you change it to `yum`? Is the new image Alpine based or not?

Comment: i am not using alpine anymore and changed to redhat/ubi8-openjdk1.8 and started receiving those errors.

Answer (score 6):

You could look at the source of the base image, and it uses `microdnf`

```
microdnf --setopt=tsflags=nodocs install -y [package...]
```

Repositories / package names should be the same as RHEL